# Form generation tool for automated generation of multiple PDF documents

Tags: forms, documentation-generator, pdf-generation

I need to manage several form documents (in fillable PDF format), and most of them share a lot of information like headers, footers and some of the fields. Right now, every time a change needs to be made, I need to manually modify every single document. I would like some kind of tool that let me automate the process, defining a common template that would work as the base of every document, so that any change to the template was propagated down without requiring manual changes.

## Requirements

- Generation of PDF documents from a source file
- HTML would be fine as source format, though other formats would work too.
- It should be possible to generate PDF forms, with named fields that's possible to integrate with other tools
- Ability of defining templates, and inheritance so any change in a template is propagated to all their children
- No restriction on platform OS (Windows, Linux...) though it must be executable from a desktop computer (no web applications if possible)

## Other notes

- Open source/free would be preferred